# Alinhar imagem ao lado de menu horizontal

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, estou com um pequeno problema, adicionei um menu horizontal ao html do site e queria colocar uma imagem ao lado (direita) porém não vai, já tentei por float, align, margin e nada, não sei se poderão me ajudar a resolver o problema, mas já agradeço a todos.

Código HTML está assim: *No caso "alignright" é só um exemplo*

```
<div id="button">
  <div class="divimg2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Aqui estão a lista do menu</a></li>
      <div class="alignright"><img src "css/images/sidimg.png"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

E o CSS está assim:

```
.alignright { float:right; }
```

Acredito que esteja faltando muita coisa (*ou não*) ao CSS pra alinhar a imagem à direita do menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocando a imagem fora da lista funciona.
Veja se assim está como quer:

```css
.alignright { float:right; }
```

```html
<div id="button">
    <div class="divimg2">
        <div class="alignright"><img src="css/images/sidimg.png"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Aqui estão a lista do menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou então experimente aqui:
https://jsfiddle.net/fbLgn88o/

Comment: Com isso adicionou a imagem porém ficou toda desalinhada e ficou por cima do menu, o link é http://barietoner.com.br/area-de-cobertura.html

Comment: deu certo agora, era só remover a "div alignright" de dentro da div button, obrigado @Edu

Answer (score 1):

Basta atribuir o valor `table` ao `display` do menu ou incluir um [clearfix](http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/clearfix.html) dentro do menu. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```css
.divimg2 {
  background: #eeeeee;
  width: 400px;
  display: table;
}

.divimg2 ul {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.divimg2 ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.divimg2 img {
  float: right; 
}
```

```html
<!-- Holder.js (apenas para carregar imagem de exemplo) -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/imsky/holder/master/holder.js"></script>

<!-- Menu -->
<div id="button">
  <div class="divimg2">
    <ul>
      <img data-src="holder.js/60x24?text=Imagem&theme=industrial">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Execute o trecho de código para ver o resultado e ver se é exatamente isso que quer.